# Count down and then up

Tags: python, recursion, counting

I need to write a code that counts down, decreasing with 2 steps until it reaches zero, where it then counts up again with 1 step between each integer.
As an example , if I define a function `updown(n)` and write `updown(7)`, it should give:

```
6 4 2 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

Here is my attempt:

```
def updown(n,m):
    while n>=1:
        print(n-1)
        n=n-m

    while n<=7:
        print(n)
        n=n+1
```

It takes m steps down, in my case `m=2`. When I run the code I get

```
 6 4 2 0 -1 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7
```

As you can see, a negative integer appear and that is wrong. Also, I have n<=7 in the code, which I know is wrong. It should be valid for any n I insert and use that value as an upper limit.

I'm stuck and don't know what to do. It should be a recursive code and no built-in functions shall be used. The reason is that I want to understand the basics and continue from there, without any shortcuts.

Comment: why should the first printed value be a 6? Shouldn't it be 7?

Comment: I forgot that It should give every even number and decrease with 2 steps. Sorry

Comment: Your starting code isn't recursive.  A recursive function is one that calls itself.  If this is an assignment for a programming course, then you should rethink your implementation.  Something like [this](http://pastebin.com/raw/dXiNwgVh) would be recursive (also a bit convoluted, I just wrote that up quickly as an example).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that by using `n-1`, you will make things more complicated than they should be.

Simply first calculate the largest even number that is smaller than the given number:

```
n2 = n-(n%2)
```

or more general (for `m`):

```
nm = n-(n%m)
```

Next use [`range`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#range):

```
for i in range(nm,-1,-m):
    print(i)
```

and finally print all number from `0` and including `n`:

```
for i in range(n+1):
    print(i)
```

or putting it all together:

```
def updown(n,m):
    nm = n-(n%m)
    for i in range(nm,-1,-m):
        print(i)
    for i in range(n+1):
        print(i)
```

From my own experience, it is rather *un-pythonic* to modify variables. Python aims to be a bit declarative: you use `for` loops if a variable can have different values to iterate over it.

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to explain! Appreciate it!

Answer (score 2):

You dont need any while loop,

You can use `range` like this,

```
>>> range(6,-2,-2) + range(1,8)
[6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

Function:

```
def updown(n, m):
    return range(n -1, -1 * m, -2) + range(1,n+1)
```

**Output:**

```
[6, 4, 2, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
```

> range(start, stop[, step])
>
> This is a versatile function to create lists containing arithmetic
>   progressions. It is most often used in for loops. The arguments must
>   be plain integers. If the step argument is omitted, it defaults to 1.
>   If the start argument is omitted, it defaults to 0. The full form
>   returns a list of plain integers [start, start + step, start + 2 *
>   step, ...]. If step is positive, the last element is the largest start
>   + i * step less than stop; if step is negative, the last element is the smallest start + i * step greater than stop. step must not be zero
>   (or else ValueError is raised).

Comment: Perhaps it is worth adding a link to the range function since documentation improves/modifies over time. +1 anyway.

Answer (score 2):

A recursive way to do the same

```
def updown(n,m = 2):
    if n % 2 == 0:
        updownhelper(-n,n,m)
    else:
        updownhelper(-(n-1),n,m)

def updownhelper(a ,n,b = 2):
    if a < 0:
        print(str(-a))
        updownhelper(a+b,n,b)
    elif a == n:
        print(a)
    elif a >= 0:
        b = 1
        print(str(a))
        updownhelper(a+b,n,b)

updown(6)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why the first printed value should be 6 so the solution might be wrong but if you want your output try:

```
def updown(n,m):
    start = n
    #n -= 1
    # or if you want the first number that is divisible by m:
    n = m * (n // m)  # Floor division ignores decimal places so this is the first number divisible by m

    while n >= m:
        print(n)
        n -= m

    while n <= start:
        print(n)
        n += 1


updown(7, 2)
```

The problem with your solution was that you printed before you subtracted so the value was actually smaller than the one printed, so you printed a negative value in the second while loop. You need to reconsider the termination condition if you print and then change the value (what I have done). Or change the order of print and operation.

Comment: If I read the comments correctly, counting should start at the first *even* number, it is however possible that `n=6`...

Comment: @Newbie_01 No problem. Don't forget to upvote any useful answer.

Comment: @MSeifert he/she cant upvote, there is not enough reputation.

Answer (score 1):

That hardcoded `7` in your example is the same parameter `n`, so you should be using that instead. And you can *"reset"* or begin the second loop from `0` (hardcoded).

```
def updown(n,m):

    aux = n # Don't modify n

    while aux > 1: # Use aux instead of n
                   # Also, `>=` changed for `>`
                   # so `0` is not counted in this loop
        print(aux - 1)
        aux = aux - m

    aux = 0 # aux reseted

    while aux <= n: # See how n take place for 7
        print(aux)
        aux = aux + 1
```

But, for that specific task is more common to use the [range function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-range) and the [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#for-statements) instead of the `while` loop and the using of manual counter. To give you an idea (and let you redefine your function as *"homework"*),...

Here is a `for` loop using the `range` function to print the numbers from `0` to `7` one by one:

```
for i in range(8):
    print(i)
```

And here is a `for` loop using the `range` function to print the numbers from `6` to `2` two by two:

```
for i in range(6, 0, -2):
    print(i)
```

Finally, you could use the [chain method from itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.chain) to do the same action for each iteration of many loops, as your case, where you want to simply *print* a number in each loop. This way, you have not to repeat that *print* statement (or in a future, repeat that *processing* block).

Here is an example chaining the two `for` loops exposed:

```
from itertools import chain

for i in chain(range(6, 2, -2), range(8)):
    print(i) # Processor block
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all you call `updown(7, 2)` it decreases to 1: `7, 5, 3, 1` then it runs again because statement `while 1 >= 1` is `True` so it decreases one more time.

The second problem it that when you decrease it output `print(n - 1)` not `print(n)`

I believe your solution is that.

```
def updown(n, m):
    while n >= m:
        print(n)
        n = n - m

    while n <= 7:
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
```

However if you want to start with even number the solution is that:

```
def updown(n, m):
    if n % 2 != 0:
        n = n - 1
    while n >= m:
        print(n)
        n = n - m

    while n <= 7:
        print(n)
        n = n + 1
```